# How to search an array of search strings with Lucene.Net

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I want to know if we can search an array of values for one field in Lucene?

For example:

```
String s[] = {"John","Daniel", "Doe"---------------------------until 50 or 1000};
```

All the string values are for FirstName field. Is it possible to search for multiple values in one field without making the operation expensive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do,

```
fieldName: John Daniel Doe ...
```

All terms will be `OR`ed, so the result set will contain all documents that matched any of the values.

The code to generate such query can be,

```
var nameValues = new[] { "John", "Daniel", "Doe", ... };
var query = new QueryParser(currentVersion, fieldName, analyzer)
                .Parse(string.Join(" ", nameValues))
```

Comment: Thanks.However,My query is taking about 5 seconds to display the result. Well actually my scenario is a bit more complicated. The String[]array values are the result from my Search. I don't really want to store them and then retrieve.I want to take the result from a search and then research I guess. Let me explain you my scenario. Lets say I search for a person Named John. I want to limit the results of John to a particular area "722204" then if I get a hit for John in area 722204 then I want to take its ID and then search again to find all the Johns with same ID irrespective of their area.

Comment: This query is working very well though. In short is there a way while searching to go back and re search?

Comment: I'm thinking you could just retrieve the one 'John' and then using its `Id` do another search, perhaps against a different field. You would have to explain your business logic more abstractly  to get a *big picture* of the user case.

Comment: You are thinking right. But you see because I am searching two times the time for searching is increasing. What is your email. Let me send you my code that way you can understand it better.